# Install4J with Java 1.6 & security

Tags: java, install4j

I'm about to release a new version of my app. I'd prefer to stick with Java 1.6 since it's been fully tested using that JVM. I use install4J.

On the Mac I don't package a JVM, relying on the presence of Apple's JVM. As I understand it they've disabled the browser plugin by default so security isn't an issue.

I do however package a 1.6 JVM with the windows version. Am I correct in believing that the packaged 1.6 JVM doesn't have and more security risks than the latest 1.7 JVM since it won't be used by the browsers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thats just a question of updated software, older versions still safe. but using then in the browser can be such a problem just because of websites checking java version.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml

take a look at that link it should help